# Sharepoint Online search REST api - filtering news pages on select sites

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, sharepoint-search

Using the search api to pull content into a mobile app, what's the right way to filter the results to get news from 2 select sites? Is there a way to use the actual site name in the filter or does it have to be the "webId"? Here's the url I'd *like* to use to illustrate what I mean:

```
https://xxx.sharepoint.com/_api/search/query?querytext='IsDocument:True AND FileExtension:aspx AND PromotedState:2'&selectproperties='Author,Path,Title,Url,CanvasContent1OWSHTML'&$filter=SiteTitle eq site1 or SiteTitle eq site2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Demo:

```
 /_api/search/query?querytext='IsDocument=true  FileExtension:aspx  Path:https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/dev Path:https://contoso.sharepoint.com/ '
```

[image]

Comment: Makes sense but I was hoping to avoid using site url paths to limit the character count. This works for now though - thanks!